# Show the variance term of the Agresti-Coull confidence interval is at least as large as the variance term for the score interval

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

We have the Agresti-Coull confidence interval

$\tilde{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\tilde{p}(1-\tilde{p})}{\tilde{n}}}$

Where $\tilde{p}=\frac{y+z_{\alpha/2}^2/2}{n+z_{\alpha/2}^2}$ and $\tilde{n}=n+z^2_{\alpha/2}$.

There are statements that say we can show the variance of the above is at least as large as the weighted average of the variances for the Wilson score interval
ie.

$\frac{\tilde{p}(1-\tilde{p})}{\tilde{n}}\geq \frac{1}{n+z_{\alpha/2}^2}\left[\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})(\frac{n}{n+z_{\alpha/2}^2})+(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{z_{\alpha/2}^2}{n+z_{\alpha/2}^2})\right]$.

I am confused how to show this using Jensen's inequality.